# Count changes in table columns in same table row

Tags: sql, database, count, netezza, unpivot

I'm struggling to figure out how to do something like this.  I have a SQL table that looks like this.  I want to add the column that totals the number of Servicer IDs that each product has during the year.  In the table called 'Years Servicer Count':

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| Product ID  | Jan Servicer ID | Feb Servicer ID | Mar Servicer ID | Apr Servicer ID | May Servicer ID | Jun Servicer ID | Jul Servicer ID | Aug Servicer ID | Sep Servicer ID | Oct Servicer ID | Nov Servicer ID | Dec Servicer ID | Years Servicer Count |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| ID-001-2015 | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-02      | SRVR-ID-02      | 2                    |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| ID-002-2015 | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | 1                    |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
| ID-002-2016 | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-01      | SRVR-ID-02      | SRVR-ID-02      | SRVR-ID-02      | SRVR-ID-02      | SRVR-ID-02      | SRVR-ID-02      | SRVR-ID-03      | SRVR-ID-03      | 3                    |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around counting the number of distinct values in a column.  Any nudge in the right direction would be amazing.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This would be much simpler to answer if the columns were in rows rather than separate columns.

Comment: Added Netezza @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Remember: A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `union all` in a subquery to unpivot the columns to rows, then `count(distinct)`:

```
select
    t.*,
    (
        select count(distinct servicer_id)
        from (
            select t.jan_servicer_id as servicer_id
            union all select t.feb_servicer_id
            union all select t.mar_servicer_id
            ...
            union all select t.dec_servicer_id
        ) t
    ) as years_servicer_count
from mytable t
```

If that's to much nesting for netezza, then another approach is a join:

```
select t.*, s.years_servicer_count
    
from mytable t
inner join (
    select product_id, count(distinct servicer_id) as years_servicer_count
    from (
        select product_id, jan_servicer_id as servicer_id from mytable
        union all select product_id, feb_servicer_id from mytable
        union all select product_id, mar_servicer_id from mytable
        ...
        union all select product_id, dec_servicer_id from mytable
    ) t
    group by product_id
) s on s.product_id = t.product_id
```

Comment: I've thought about doing this, but I have 100,000+ rows.  To put it back would be terrible.

Comment: @JoeWolf: I can't see another way around this. The primary problem is with the design of your table (these columns should be rows instead), which the above queries attempt to work around. Give it a try. Performance might not be that bad.

Comment: 100000 rows is still a lot in a spreadsheet, but on Netezza it’s considered ‘very small’ :) the union all approach seems perfectly ok to me?